# MATLAB cellfun() to map contains() to cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

```
a={'hello','world','friends'};
```

I want to see if for every word in the cell array contains the letter 'o', how to use `cellfun()` to achieve the following in a compact expression?

```
   b = [ contains(a(1),'o')  contains(a(2),'o')  contains(a(3),'o')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `cellfun`, if you read [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contains.html), `contains` works natively on cell arrays of characters:

```
a = {'hello', 'world', 'friends'};
b = contains(a, 'o');
```

Which returns:

```
b =

  1×3 logical array

   1   1   0
```